# concatenate id to laravel request inside controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with multiple select box with quantity beside it, now in my controller I will loop the select box and get the quantity of that select box, I think of concatenating the `id` of the selected value in selectbox to the request `quantity`

Blade:

```
<form>
    @foreach($packages as $package)
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="packages[]" value="{{ $package->id}}">
            {{ $package->name }}
        </label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity_{{ $package->id }}">
    @endforeach 
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function add(Request $request) {
    
    foreach($request->packages[] as $package) {
       echo $package->id .'<br>';
       echo $quantity_of_this_package; // should get the quantity of that package
    }

}
```

how to know the quantity of the selected package? is concatenating a good solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be using the array notation for the other input as well, but telling it what key to use:

```
type="number" name="quantity[{{ $package->id }}]"
```

Then on the server side:

```
foreach ($request->input('packages', []) as $id)) {
    echo "Package ID: ". $id ."\n";
    echo "Quantity: ". $request->input('quantity.'. $id) ."\n";
}
```